# Implementing IEnumerable<T> for self-referencing type cause StackOverflow in NUnit "Assert.AreEquals"

Tags: c#, nunit, stack-overflow, equality

In my project I tried to implement Java-like enum based on this [post](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/). I needed it for Entity Framework because we wanted a way to save enums in database as string. This actually works just fine, that's not the real issue here.

It turned out, that `Assert.AreEqual()` in NUnit crashes when it tries to enumerate over properties of my class. I checked out what happened to find out, that because of self-reference in my objects, it tries to enumerate over the same object over and over obviously causing StackOverflow (log below). The function that cause exception is `AbstractStringEnum.GetEnumerator`

My code could work without IEnumerable interface, but it bugs me how should I implement it, so circular dependency wouldn't be a case.

Any idea how to improve my code is priceless.

> Test class:

```cs
[TestFixture]
internal class AbstractStringEnumTests
{
    private class AbstractStringEnumMock : AbstractStringEnum<AbstractStringEnumMock>
    {
        public enum Items
        {
            Item0
        }

        public static readonly AbstractStringEnumMock Item0 = new AbstractStringEnumMock(Items.Item0);

        private AbstractStringEnumMock()
        {
        }

        private AbstractStringEnumMock(Items value) : base(value.ToString())
        {
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ThrowStackOverflowException()
    {
        // Arrange
        var stringValue = AbstractStringEnumMock.Item0.ToString();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(AbstractStringEnumMock.Item0, stringValue); // crash!!!
    }
}
```

> Tested abstract class:

```cs
public abstract class AbstractStringEnum<T> : IComparable where T : AbstractStringEnum<T>
{
    protected AbstractStringEnum()
    {
    }

    protected AbstractStringEnum(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; protected set; }

    //
    // overloaded operators
    //

    // Override reference equals to provide a value equals since the type is (almost) immutable.
    public static bool operator ==(AbstractStringEnum<T> a, AbstractStringEnum<T> b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, b))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (a is null || b is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var typeMatches = a.GetType().Equals(b.GetType());
        var valueMatches = a.Value.Equals(b.Value);

        return typeMatches && valueMatches;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(AbstractStringEnum<T> a, AbstractStringEnum<T> b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    //
    // public instance methods
    //

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is AbstractStringEnum<T> otherValue))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var typeMatches = GetType().Equals(obj.GetType());
        var valueMatches = Value.Equals(otherValue.Value);

        return typeMatches && valueMatches;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        return Value.CompareTo(((AbstractStringEnum<T>)other).Value);
    }

    //
    // public static methods
    //

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllSupportedValues()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        {
            var enumeration = field.GetValue(type) as T;

            // If the static field is an Enumeration type.
            if (enumeration != null)
            {
                yield return enumeration;
            }
        }
    }

    public static T FromValue(string value)
    {
        return _parse(value, "value", item => item.Value == value);
    }

    //
    // private static methods
    //

    private static T _parse<K>(K value, string description, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var matchingItem = GetAllSupportedValues().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

        if (matchingItem == null)
        {
            var message = $"'{value}' is not a valid {description} in {typeof(T)}";
            throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }

        return matchingItem;
    }
}
```

Here is what NUnit log after running tests. It crash every unit-tests in project because of StackOverflowException.

```
[21.08.2019 08:58:41 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 3 run (0:00:01,7459266) ==========
[21.08.2019 09:40:43 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[21.08.2019 09:40:44 Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
[21.08.2019 09:40:44 Informational] Running all tests in ###
[21.08.2019 09:40:44 Informational]    NUnit3TestExecutor converted 4 of 4 NUnit test cases
[21.08.2019 09:40:50 Error] The active test run was aborted. Reason: Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

[21.08.2019 09:40:50 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:07,0638228) ==========
```

@Edit
Okay, that may be some misunderstanding. Test case in my example is just silly part of code that triggered error. It's not the real example of test. I placed it here, because that's the smallest, working thing that triggers exception as well as NUnit log above.

Comment: Your Assert.AreEqual() can never be true because `AbstractStringEnumMock.Item0` is of type `AbstractStringEnumMock` and `stringValue` is, of course, of type `string`. Is this really the actual code?

Comment: Why don't you debug your test?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Of course. This dumb test case is just silly thing my coworker did while unit-testing something. That's when he found out that StackOverflow crashes all his tests.
Test is just simple way to crash whole UnitTests framework which is a very bad and I think of a way to avoid it.

Comment: Well, this code works as expected if you use the `Assert.AreEqual()` from Microsoft, so it would appear to be an issue with NUnit.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the NUnit design is that it has a special definition of equality as applies to enumerables. So when you test that two enumerables are equal, you are essentially telling NUnit to enumerate them. I believe (haven't looked at the latest code for a while) that you can avoid the problem if your class overrides `Equals` or implements the IEquatable interface. Note that both of the objects you are comparing are enumerable, since the second one is a string.

Of course, it would be lots better if the runner didn't crash! So it's probably something you should report as a bug.